# Return value of the dropdown list rather than text when creating an item

Tags: list, external-list

I'm following [this](http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-3-creating-a-custom-editing-interface.html) example.

I have a dropdown on the create new item page (external list). And I'd like to get the value of the selected item rather than the text.

Please see my code below, at the server side (c# code) keeps getting the selected text.

Does anyone knows what have I done wrong?

```
var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);

formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, getFieldValue.bind(null, formCtx.fieldName));

// items to appear in the drop down list
var items = new Array("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3");
var returnHtml = "<div id=" + ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name + "><select>";

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    returnHtml += "<option value='value" + i + "'";
    if (ctx.CurrentFieldValue == items[i]) {
        // select the current item if the value matches
        returnHtml += " selected ";
    }
    returnHtml += ">" + items[i] + "</option>";
}

returnHtml += "</select></div>";
return returnHtml;


getFieldValue = function (fieldName) {
    var divId = "#" + fieldName;
    return $(divId + ' option:selected')[0].value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165315/how-to-get-the-selected-text-instead-of-value-in-dropdown-menu

Reposting that answer here:

If you have something like

```
<select>
    <option value='1'> SO</option>
    <option value='2'>GOOGLE</option>
</select>
```

you can try

```
$("select").change(function(e){
    console.log($(":selected",this).text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ykzp7/